# Sending javascript array to rest method

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

```
 vm.finalFilter=[];
 vm.finalFilter.push(item.id);    
 SubscribeContext.getAllFilteredContexts({
              page: pagingParams.page - 1,
              size: vm.itemsPerPage,
              contextTypeId: vm.finalFilter,
              status: '',

          }, onSuccess, onError);
```

MY REST service:

```
 @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Context>> getAllFilteredContexts(@ApiParam Pageable pageable,List<Long> contextTypeId,String status) 
            throws URISyntaxException, JSONException {

}
```

I want to send an javascript array to my rest method but always contextTypeId is empty.My finalFilter array contains id numbers.How can i send?Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By saying empty do you mean to say that the contextTypeId param receives an  empty array? If yes, check for the item.id value instead.

Comment: Yes.contextTypeId param receives an empty array.item.id value is not empty